# Python Importing with OOP

Tags: python, oop, import

This question concerns when you should have imports for Python modules and how it all interacts when you are trying to take an OOP approach to what you're making.

Let's say we have the following Modules:

ClassA.py:

```
class Class_A:

    def doSomething(self):
        #doSomething
```

ClassB.py

```
class Class_B:

    def doSomethingElse(self):
        #doSomethingElse
```

ClassC.py

```
class Class_C:

    def __init__(self, ClassAobj, ClassBobj):
        self.a = ClassAobj
        self.b = ClassBobj

    def doTheThing(self):
        self.a.doSomething()
        self.b.doSomethingElse()
```

Main.py:

```
from ClassA import Class_A
from ClassB import Class_B
from ClassC import Class_C

a = Class_A()
b = Class_B()
c = Class_C(a,b)
```

In here `Class_C` uses objects of `Class_A` and `Class_B` however it does not have import statements for those classes.  Do you see this creating errors down the line, or is this fine?  Is it bad practice to do this?

Would having imports for `Class_A` and `Class_B` inside of `Class_C` cause the program as a whole to use more memory since it would be importing them for both `Main.py` and `ClassC.py`?  Or will the Python compiler see that those modules have already been imported and just skip over them?

I'm just trying to figure out how Python as a language ticks with concerns to importing and using modules.  Basically, if at the topmost level of your program (your Main function) if you import everything there, would import statements in other modules be redundant?

Comment: that is what [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) is about. the interpreter does not care about what `ClassAobj` is - it only cares that the class provides the methods you call on that object (e.g. when you call `self.a.doSomething()`, then this method must be defined for this instance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use Class_A or Class_B directly in Class_C, so you don't need to import them there.

Extra imports don't really use extra memory, there is only a single instance of each module in memory. Import just creates a name for the module in the current module namespace.

In Python, it's *not* idiomatic to have a single class per file. It's normal to have closely related classes all in the same file. A module name "ClassA" looks silly, that is the name of a class, not of a module.

You can only use a module inside another one if it's imported there. For instance the `sys` module is probably already in memory after Python starts, as so many things use it, including import statements.

An `import foo` statement does two things:

- If the `foo` module is not in memory yet, it is loaded, parsed, executed and then placed in `sys.modules['foo']`.
- A local name `foo` is created that also refers to the module in `sys.modules`.

So if you have say a `print()` in your module (not inside a function), then that is only executed the first time the module is imported.

Then later statements after the import can do things with `foo`, like `foo.somefunc()` or `print(foo.__name__)`.

Comment: Sorry, I just made an edit, because `Class_C` was suppose to call the methods in `Class_A` and `Class_B`.

Comment: As for "don't put one class per module", yes I understand that.  :)

Answer (score 1):

`C` does not need the `import` statements; all it uses is a pair of object handles (i.e. pointers).  As long as it does not try to access any method or attribute of those objects, the pure assignment is fine.  If you *do* need such additions, then you need the `import` statements.

This will not cause additional memory usage in `Main`: Python checks (as do most languages) packages already imported, and will not import one multiple times.  Note that this sometimes means that you have to be careful of package dependencies and importation order.

Answer (score 0):

Importing a module does two things: it executes the code stored in the module, and it adds name bindings to the module doing the importing. `ClassC.py` doesn't need to import `ClassA` or `ClassB` because it doesn't know or care what types the arguments to `ClassC.__init__` have, as long as they behave properly when used. Any references to code needed by either object is stored in the object itself.